# Sufficient condition for fractal dimension of continuous nowhere differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fractals

As usual, for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the graph of $f$ is the set $\{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. For which continuous nowhere differentiable functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ does the graph of $f$ have fractional fractal (Box or Hausdorff) dimension?

The Weirstrass function has fractional Hausdorff dimension. But, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74936/are-all-continuous-everywhere-but-nowhere-differentiable-functions-fractal-in-na), one can construct examples of such functions with integer fractal dimension.

Are there sufficient conditions for such functions to have fractional fractal dimension?

Comment: Related: [the box counting dimension of $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is equal to $3/2$](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136755/MathSlov_49-1999-3_13.pdf).

Comment: Being "uniform wiggly" is enough: $\exists c>0$ and $p\in (0, 1)$ such that $\operatorname{osc}_{[a, b]}f \ge c(b-a)^p$ for all intervals $[a, b]$. But I'm not about to write a proof of that. (Also, this is sufficient to have dimension _greater than 1_; it may be equal to $2$.)